# Obtain beautiful GUI like Adobe ones

Tags: c++, user-interface

Before someone closes my question, I will explain:
I'm trying to create in a native application (C++, Windows only, 64bit) a smart and beautiful interface.
QT and wxWidget don't satisfy me (QT is slow, huge exe size; wxW is ugly). I'm looking for something more sophisticated.
Take a look: ([link](http://bestvideotutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/maxresdefault11.jpg)) 
[image]
Probably they didn't use QT nor wxWidget nor GTK+ (the ugliest one).
My question is not 'what did they use to make such a beatiful GUI' but '**which tecnologies can I use to obtain a similar result**'?

My idea was to create a webpage like design, with my custom buttons, custom forms...
I tried Awesomium that renders directly a webpage but it's not healty to handle JS-CPP communication.
Any interoperability is ok
Every good idea is welcome, including handling XML, HTML, CSS, XAML
Just exclude what I have already used (wxWideget, QT, Mozilla's XUL, Awesomium, GTK+)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just note that "boring native controls" is GOOD, because every user in the worlds knows those controls and how to operate those! ...imho that adobe thing is probably done with 100% custom controls, using just canvases

Comment: @Exceptyon boring native controls are indeed good, but still boring.

Comment: Take a look at [JUCE (Jules' Utility Class Extensions)](http://www.juce.com)

Comment: Custom controls are a reasonable approach for a user's core application. Does your user spend 20 hours/week in your application? Mind you, controls _should_ be boring. No user is going to use your application because you have "exciting" controls.

Comment: why off topic? there are tons of questions that asks for a library... however, JUCE doesn't fit :( good answer but no

Comment: however, I know that a good interface doesn't make a good application, but I still want to make my software different from the other. From features and user interface. And yes, it will be a productivity software, the user will spend (8x5) = 40h/week

Comment: Question edited. I hope it's ok now

Comment: This question should not have been closed. It is a very interesting question I'm sure many people will want to know the answer to. StackOverflow fail.

Comment: Actually at least photoshop elements is built with Qt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot produce a UI of that calibre with anything that goes through GDI or GDI+. You need genuine alpha channel and animations, and probably textures and GPU assist, which means you need the games interface based on DirectX.

There are 4 technologies built on DirectX, that I know of.

1. DirectX itself, with or without XNA on top. That means writing a render loop. DirectX is native C++/COM, XNA is C#.
2. WPF/XAML. Easiest to use in C#/VB, but can be done in managed C++.
3. Silverlight/XAML. Should be doable in managed C++, but not recommended now.
4. Store App/XAML. Again, easiest to use in C#/VB, but can be done in managed C++. Absolutely brilliant animations, skinned controls, rather limited deployment options.

There could well be third party products built on top of these, but I wouldn't know. With these tools you can do what you ask, with time the only cost.

Comment: yes probably this is the point. using directx for creating a gui is not mentally healty. maybe sdl?

Comment: however, just the first point is ok. WPF and Silverlight and Store apps aren't native

Comment: finally, I decided to use Awesomium. I think it's good enough

Comment: My intent was to give a canonical answer for the Windows platform, and avoid being closed for "recommend a tool or library". Guess I didn't quite make it. You _can_ use XAML/WPF through interop (and you mentioned it). Seems Awesomium is HTML, so it will be interesting to see how far it takes you.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. It's a good idea :) I'll give it a try, thanks